# Call API return XML, how to use XmlSerializer to Deserialize the file to object?

Tags: xml, api, serialization, xsd, xmlserializer

Recently I spent quite some time on these, and want to write down some notes, hopefully it helps.
Step 1: Make the API call, notice the contentType is: "application/xml" 
you can check Sample code below.
Step 2: The tricky part is how to create the class of "myObject".
        If the object is not completely matching the XML return, then you will always get XML deserialize error and have no clue.

Check my answer below for creating .cs class which could correct deserialize.

```
try
            {
                byte[] bHeaderBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(GetUserPasswordString());
                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(cRequestString);
                request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
                request.PreAuthenticate = true;
                request.ContentType = "application/xml";
                request.Accept = "application/xml";
                request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(bHeaderBytes));
                HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
                xmlDoc.Load(response.GetResponseStream());                                                           
                XmlNodeReader xReader = new XmlNodeReader(xmlDoc.DocumentElement);           
                return (myObject)xSerializer.Deserialize(xReader);                
            }
            catch
            {
                return null;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Debug the code, after ran this line, check xmlDoc -> innerXML, copy to a text file and save as .xml at local. You may go to online XML validation website to make sure the XML is valid one. Sometimes some extra characters will be added which causing problems.

   xmlDoc.Load(response.GetResponseStream());
2. Create .xsd file, this could be done online.
3. Create class file eg: .cs from .xsd file by the [xsd.exe](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/229875/install-xsdexe.html) (could be download)
   You may want to add a variable path for this exe.
   After installed, you can open Visual Studio Command Propmpt-->
   Enter:  c:\temp>xsd.exe sample.xsd /classes
   then the .cs file will be created in the same folder.